# Fan on always on HP Notebook AMD A8-7410 APU

Tags: 16.04, fan

I have an HP Notebook with AMD A8-7410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics × 4 and Ubuntu 16.04 as the OS. The fan of the laptop always stays on while the CPU temperatures, as noted by psensor, have been between 35 and 58°C.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link to learn more about possibilities as to why the fan is always on. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-constantfan.html